# any way to use JavaSparkContext in JavaRdd.map(rdd -> {})?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am thinking doing the following code. However, I got an error saying JavaSparkContext (sc) is not serializable. I am wondering if there is anyway to bypass this?

```
javaRdd.map(rdd -> {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    for (EntityA a : rdd) {
                        String json = null;
                        try {
                            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(a);
                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        data.add(json);
                    }
                    JavaRDD<String> rddData = sc.parallelize(data);
                    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().schema(schema).json(rddData);
   });
```

Comment: This is not possible for many reasons, 1. The items in RDD must be Serializable and RDD is not, same with SparkContext.

Comment: you can have spark context only from the master node and slave nodes which run workers cannot have sparkContext and neither be created because spark people have cautiously made sparkContext,spark and other session objects non-serializable.